# Flash message in AJAX rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a *`Products`*  and product *`Reviews`* controller. Im trying to display a Flash message (`"Your review is under review for approval"`) in my AJAX rendering when a review is created. Not sure how do i go about doing so.

> Review Controller

```
def create
  @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  @review = Review.new(review_params)
  @review.user = current_user
  @review.product = @product
  respond_to do |format|
    if @review.save
      format.html { redirect_to product_path(@product), flash[:notice]="Your review is under review for approval" }
      format.js {render :create_success}
    else
      format.html { render "products/show" }
      format.js {render :create_failure}
    end
  end
end
```

> create_success.js.erb

```
$("#reviews").prepend("<%= j render '/reviews/review', review: @review %>");
<% @review = Review.new %>
$("#new_review").replaceWith("<%= j render 'review_form' %>")
```

> index.html.erb

```
<div  class="reviews" id="<%= dom_id(review)%>">
</div>

<%= simple_form_for [@product, @review], remote: true do |f| %>
 <div class="form-group">
   <%= f.input :review_comment, placeholder: "Let us know what you think here..."%>
 </div> 
 <div>
   <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn review-form-btn" %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Just add a DOM element and bind your flash message to it. Ex: add this to view template: `<div id="flash_notice"></div>` , then in your **create.js.erb**  do:   `$("#flash_notice").html("Your review is under review for approval");`

Comment: @dkp saved my day! thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step-1:**

Add an element to DOM as follows:

```
<div id="flash_notice"></div>
```

**Step-2:**

Render flash message to DOM in `create.js.erb` :

```
$("#flash_notice").html("Your review is under review for approval");
```

Comment: this works perfectly but i have another issue where this seems to work only once after I reload the page and make my AJAX call/render. If i try to submit another review without reloading the page it won't display the `#flash_notice`. Is there a way to fix this?